# g++ ultra verbosity nightmare

Tags: templates, g++

This is for a single error. I had to cut it down in order to post it here. How to disable this madness ? (g++ 5.3.1)

```
user@computer:~/projectClient# ./build 

project/update.cpp: In function ‘bool is_recentlyProcessed(IntervalTime, ulong)’:
project/update.cpp:71:80: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ and ‘std::map<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > >}’)
  return !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end
                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/set:60:0,
                 from project/update.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:312:7: note: candidate: bool std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator==(const _Self&) const [with _Tp = long unsigned int; std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::_Self = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>]
       operator==(const _Self& __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:312:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::map<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > >}’ to ‘const _Self& {aka const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>&}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/stack:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/reader.h:15,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:11,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_stack.h:246:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Seq> bool std::operator==(const std::stack<_Tp, _Seq>&, const std::stack<_Tp, _Seq>&)
     operator==(const stack<_Tp, _Seq>& __x, const stack<_Tp, _Seq>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_stack.h:246:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::stack<_Tp, _Seq>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/reader.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:11,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:2220:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const deque<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:2220:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/reader.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:11,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:272:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _RefL, class _PtrL, class _RefR, class _PtrR> bool std::operator==(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefR, _PtrR>&)
     operator==(const _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefL, _PtrL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:272:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/reader.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:11,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:265:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Ref, class _Ptr> bool std::operator==(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&)
     operator==(const _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_deque.h:265:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:62:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/value.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:10,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_multimap.h:974:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_multimap.h:974:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/value.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h:10,
                 from project/../parser/parser.h:5,
                 from project/../data.h:5,
                 from project/update.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:1073:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:1073:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:347:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:347:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:15: note:   cannot convert ‘std::find<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>, long unsigned int>((& recentlyProcessed.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int>, std::less<IntervalTime>, std::allocator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > > >(it))->std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin<long unsigned int, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >(), (& recentlyProcessed.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int>, std::less<IntervalTime>, std::allocator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > > >(it))->std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::end<long unsigned int, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >(), id)’ (type ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’) to type ‘std::nullptr_t’
  return !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:342:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&, std::nullptr_t)
     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:342:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:336:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp1, class _Tp2> bool std::operator==(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>&, const std::shared_ptr<_Tp2>&)
     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp1>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:336:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::shared_ptr<_Tp1>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1194:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&)
     operator==(nullptr_t, const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1194:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:15: note:   cannot convert ‘std::find<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>, long unsigned int>((& recentlyProcessed.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int>, std::less<IntervalTime>, std::allocator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > > >(it))->std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin<long unsigned int, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >(), (& recentlyProcessed.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int>, std::less<IntervalTime>, std::allocator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > > >(it))->std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::end<long unsigned int, std::less<long unsigned int>, std::allocator<long unsigned int> >(), id)’ (type ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’) to type ‘std::nullptr_t’
  return !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1189:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&, std::nullptr_t)
     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1189:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:82,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:40,
                 from project/update.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1183:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp1, class _Tp2, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>&, const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>&)
     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __a,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1183:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/set:62:0,
                 from project/update.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_multiset.h:825:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_multiset.h:825:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/set:61:0,
                 from project/update.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_set.h:842:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_set.h:842:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/set:60:0,
                 from project/update.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:1273:5: note: candidate: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:1273:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^




   ....






In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:134:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp>&, const std::allocator<_Tp>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:134:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_Tp>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp>&, const std::allocator<_Tp>&)
     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:128:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_Tp>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: candidate: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1071:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1071:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1065:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:1065:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:342:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:342:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:292:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:292:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/utility:70:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:60,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:214:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     operator==(const new_allocator<_Tp>&, const new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:827:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:827:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:61,
                 from project/update.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
project/update.cpp:71:105: note:   ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’
 urn !(find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id) == recentlyProcessed.end());
                                                                                                     ^
user@computer:~/projectClient#
```

Here's the build command (it doesn't make a difference if i remove -Wall):

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-format-contains-nul -std=c++11 -D${JSON} \
  -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -lssl -lcrypto -ljsoncpp \
  -o bin/client client.cpp common.cpp update.cpp
```

Comment: Only the 4 first lines were helpful to solve this. Everything else was irrelevant and should be disable by default. What make things even worst is that I didn't find any option to remove this junk. As a side note, I'm not looking for a fix for the error, not even for a solution at all. Gcc's guys should just be aware of this mess.

Answer (score 2):

While the error spew is daunting at initial glance, it can be helpful in tricky cases.  Just start at the top and work your way down until you figure out what the problem is.

In this case it looks like you're trying to compare a `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<long unsigned int>` with a `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const IntervalTime, std::set<long unsigned int> > >` which are iterators to completely different types of objects.

It seems that `find(recentlyProcessed[it].begin(), recentlyProcessed[it].end(), id)` returns an interator to a different container than what `recentlyProcessed.end` is - note that `recentlyProcessed.end` doesn't have an index.

Probably you need to compare with `recentlyProcessed[it].end` or `recentlyProcessed[it].end()` instead.

Comment: @lxndr: 65KB is pretty impressive.  On the bright side, 95% of the time you'll get what you need to know in the first few lines and you can ignore the other 64.9KB.  Just pretend that it was never spit out.  For that other 5% of the time, you probably will require the additional output to troubleshoot the problem.  Actually - I hope the numbers are more like 99.9% and 0.1%.